# Problema ao ordenar sql com orderby Date em postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, query, select, order-by

Tenho a seguinte Query que resulta na união da soma total de uma conta e as parcelas

```
select 
    sum(total) as total, 
    datavencimento 
from  (
    select 
        sum (con_valoraserpago) as total,
        to_char(con_datavencimento,'mm/yyyy') as datavencimento 
    from conta  
    where con_formapagamento='V'  
    group by datavencimento  
    union
    select 
        sum (par_valorparcela) as total,
        to_char(par_datavencimento,'mm/yyyy') as datavencimento 
    from parcela
    where par_estorno <= 0  
    group by datavencimento
) AS A 
group by datavencimento 
order by datavencimento ASC NULLS FIRST;
```

Caso eu execute select por select elas me trazem ordenados corretamente pelo union, porém quando eu utilizo o union elas acabam vindo desordenadas, como por exemplo 03/2018 vem na frente de 04/2017. eu estou mandando a data para to_char para pode colocar no formato que eu quero e quando eu for ordernar eu uso ela no formato de date, o erro é ocasionado pela união, então como eu faço para ser ordenado a data todo esse conjunto de uniao?

Saida da query

```
 total;datavencimento
    200;"01/2017"
    200;"02/2017"
    200;"02/2018"
    1534.24;"03/2017"
    200;"03/2018"
    450;"04/2017"
    50;"05/2017"
    650;"06/2017"
    2879.8;"07/2017"
    200;"08/2017"
    200;"09/2017"
    200;"10/2017"
    200;"12/2017"
```

Comment: Você precisará remover o `to_char` da subconsulta que está no `from`. Da forma atual o `order by` está sendo realizado como se `datavencimento` fosse um texto e não uma data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto vai funcionar:

```
select 
    sum(total) as total, 
    datavencimento
from  (
    select 
        sum (con_valoraserpago) as total,
        to_char(con_datavencimento,'mm/yyyy') as datavencimento,
        **date_trunc('month', con_datavencimento) as data_order**
    from conta  
    where con_formapagamento='V'  
    group by datavencimento, **data_order**  
    union
    select 
        sum (par_valorparcela) as total,
        to_char(par_datavencimento,'mm/yyyy') as datavencimento,
        **date_trunc('month', par_datavencimento) as data_order**
    from parcela
    where par_estorno <= 0  
    group by datavencimento, **data_order**
) AS A 
group by datavencimento, **data_order**
order by **data_order** ASC NULLS FIRST;
```

**[Veja o teste aqui!](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/df754/10)**

Comment: Olha só o que aparece 'ERROR:  column "conta.con_datavencimento" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 9:         con_datavencimento as data_order
                ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: column "conta.con_datavencimento" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
SQL state: 42803'   aparentemente eu não consigo utilizar o data_order como con_datavencimento, ele me da esse erro

Comment: Ahh faltou incluir a coluna nova no Order By  
<code>group by datavencimento, data_order </code>

Comment: group by datavencimento, data_order

Comment: Havia colocado esse group by data _order também, mas mesmo assim não funcionou, ocorre o mesmo erro ... Será que o erro consistem no group by interno do from? antes do union no caso

Comment: @BrunoAparecidodaSilva isso mesmo! Também esqueci deste order by interno

Comment: @BrunoAparecidodaSilva Acabei de editar a resposta e inclui um teste!

Comment: Caramba realmente agora funcionou, muito obrigado pela paciência e pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim:

```
  select sum(total) as total, datavencimento 
        from  
        (
        SELECT sum(con_valoraserpago) as total,
            to_char(con_datavencimento,'mm/yyyy') as datavencimento ,
            to_char(con_datavencimento, "yyyy/mm") as data_order
        FROM conta  where con_formapagamento='V'  
        GROUP BY datavencimento  
        UNION
        SELECT sum(par_valorparcela) as total, 
                to_char(par_datavencimento,'mm/yyyy') as datavencimento ,
                to_char(par_datavencimento, 'yyyy/mm') as data_order
        FROM parcela  
        WHERE par_estorno <= 0  
        GROUP BY datavencimento
   ) 
   AS A group by datavencimento     
   order by data_order ASC NULLS FIRST
```

Comment: Acabei me deparando com o seguinte erro ERROR:  column "yyyy/mm" does not exist
LINE 6:             to_char(con_datavencimento, "yyyy/mm") as data_o...
                                                ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: column "yyyy/mm" does not exist
SQL state: 42703

Answer (score 0):

Tenta Assim

```
select 
       sum(total) as total, 
    datavencimento 
from  (
    select 
        sum (con_valoraserpago) as total,
        to_char(con_datavencimento,'mm/yyyy') as datavencimento 
    from conta  
    where con_formapagamento='V'  
    group by datavencimento  
    union
    select 
        sum (par_valorparcela) as total,
        to_char(par_datavencimento,'mm/yyyy') as datavencimento 
    from parcela
    where par_estorno <= 0  
    group by datavencimento
) AS A 
group by datavencimento 
order by TO_DATE(datavencimento,'mm/yyyy') ASC NULLS FIRST;
```

Desta maneira, ele irá converte datavencimento de text para data e irá ordenar levando em conta mês e ano.